# pandas add a '*' for values less than .05

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of p values.

```
    disorder    p value(group)  p value(cluster)    p value(interaction)
0   Specific phobia 0.108   0.022   0.075
1   Social phobia   0.848   0.001   0.690
2   Depression  0.923   0.034   0.016
3   PTSD    0.519   0.039   0.004
4   ODD 0.013   0.053   0.003
5   ADHD    0.876   0.062   0.012
```

How can I add '*' to those values that are less than .05?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do

```
df.iloc[:,1:]=df.iloc[:,1:].mask(df.iloc[:,1:].le(0.05),df.astype(str).apply(lambda x : x.str[:5]).add('*'))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that adds star before the numbers. And it changes values to have much larger decimals. I hope to get values to appear as '.022 star'

Comment: Thanks but that still adds the star before the numbers. Is there a function to add star after the number?

Comment: I have a solution: df.applymap(lambda x: str(x)+'*' if x<.05 else str(x)). But the result contains many decimals even after I use df.round(3).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like -

```
df.astype(str)
specific_column = ['Column Name you want to check on']
df[specific_column] = df[specific_column].apply(lambda x: x + "*" if int(x)<0.5 else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured out a way to add * and ** to values less than .05 and .01, respectively.

```
report2 = report.copy()

report[report2.iloc[:,1:].le(0.05)] = report[report2.iloc[:,1:].le(0.05)].astype(str).apply(lambda x : x.str[:5]).add('*')
report[report2.iloc[:,1:].le(0.01)] = report[report2.iloc[:,1:].le(0.01)].astype(str).apply(lambda x : x.str[:5]).add('**')
```